# Conduit through wall with low power and AC

Tags: electrical, conduit, ethernet

I want to run a new 20A service and 2x POE lines from my basement to my garage. Can I put them in the same pieces of conduit or do I need two? Piece of conduit would be less than  1 foot in length.

Comment: Is the 20A service a 12/2 or 12/3 cable, or is it individual wires?

Comment: 12/2 standard 12 gauge romex. Just adding a few outlets to garage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot mix AC mains and low-voltage wiring (such as network cables) in the same conduit.  The length of the run is not important, it's prohibited.

Run two separate conduits and you'll be good.

Answer (score 2):

### There's a gizmo made for *precisely this sort of job*

While Exception 1 to NEC 800.133(A)(1)(c) or 800.133(A)(2) would permit the shared sleeve you describe, I would not bother with your conduit sleeve approach here to begin with as the fireblocking foam fill would create issues with potential cable damage during re-entry that could be quite troublesome.  Instead, if you don't mind spending a bit of money on the problem to save you a lot of fuss with foam later, I would throw a made-for-purpose gadget at this job, the [STI EZ-Path 22](https://www.stifirestop.com/products/ez-path-series-22/).  These are available through various industrial and electrical suppliers for under $100 at the time of this writing, and provide an easy-to-install, easy-to-reenter, and *proven safe* (the device I describe is UL and FM approved for full-blown penetration firestopping in places like hospitals and high-rises where that stuff matters) solution to the problem.

Comment: $50 on amazon. https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B007I9NTMC/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_pqkkFbVMB9HC4

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon -- this is the kind of thing that you, as a rule, *do not order from Amazon*.  Amazon's horrifyingly sloppy handling of product equivalence and provenance does you no favors here...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: This is the answer! I deleted my own because I touched on the issues but didn't have the exact solution.

Comment: Good tip! The way I read this answer, "for precisely this sort of job" suggests it allows putting the two in one sleeve, because that was asked. But this is not what you imply, right? The OP still needs to keep the mains and LV in separate conduits, sleeves, EZ-paths etc.. I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: Wow, Brown's Ferry nuclear plant sure could've used some of those! The real ones, not the Amazon ones lol... pure counterfeit, most likely...

Comment: @P2000 -- no, having mains *cables* (NM/UF/MC) mixed with LV cables in such a device is A-OK due to the exceptions I mentioned